# Preventing cyclic JavaScript events

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js

This problem happens to involve D3-specific functions, but is not a D3-specific problem.  I have two D3 charts that I have created and attached zoom functionality to, with the goal of keeping the zoom scale and transform positions equal, such that when one chart is zoomed, the other will automatically zoom to the same scale and location.  To do this, I trigger a custom event when one chart is zoomed so that I can automatically adjust the other chart:

```
// Within the chart definition:
var svg = ...; // The chart body definition
var zoom =  d3.behavior.zoom()
    .on("zoom", function(e){
        // do stuff...
        $("#chart-div").trigger({
            type: "my.zoom",
            translate: d3.event.translate,
            scale: d3.event.scale
        });
    });
svg.call(zoom);
```

I then create methods that allow me to adjust the zoom level of each chart manually, triggering the D3 `zoom` event in the process:

```
var adjustZoom = function(t,s){
    svg.transition().duration(500).call(zoom.scale(s).translate(t).event);
};
```

I then attach event listeners to each of my charts, so that when I interact with one of them and cause its zoom level to change, the other is updated automatically:

```
$("#chart-div1").on("my.zoom", function(e){
    chart2.adjustZoom(e.translate, e.scale);
});
$("#chart-div2").on("my.zoom", function(e){
    chart1.adjustZoom(e.translate, e.scale);
});
```

The obvious problem is that calling the `adjustZoom` method triggers the D3 `zoom` event, so attaching event listeners on both charts creates cyclical events, as each chart tries to adjust the other one infinitely.

```
1. chart1 [manual zoom]      --> trigger d3.zoom --> triggers my.zoom
2. chart2 [my.zoom listener] --> trigger d3.zoom --> triggers my.zoom
3. chart1 [my.zoom listener] --> trigger d3.zoom --> triggers my.zoom
etc...
```

What I would like to implement is a way to check whether the `my.zoom` event has already been fired when deciding to trigger another `my.zoom` event, to prevent the cyclic firing of events (prevent step 3 in the above example), but I don't know how to go about doing this.  Is there anyway for a function or event to be aware of the event that triggered it and then halt itself?

Answer (score 1):

The first option that comes to mind, if `translate` and `scale` aren't fuzzy values, is to make calling `adjustZoom` with the current `translate` and `scale` a no-op. So if chart1's values change, it raises the event, changes chart2's values, and chart2 raises the event, but chart1 breaks the cycle because its `translate` and `scale` are already those values.

Another option is to pass the source element of the change in the event, and then not trigger it on the chart if that's the chart that started it.

E.g., when triggering:

```
$("#chart-div").trigger({
    type: "my.zoom",
    translate: d3.event.translate,
    scale: d3.event.scale,
    source: this              // <=== The new bit
});
```

And then when handling:

```
if (chart2[0] !== e.source) {
    chart2.adjustZoom(e.translate, e.scale);
}
```

Note that that code example assumes `chart1` and `chart2` are jQuery wrappers around single elements; if not, adjust accordingly.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I don't think this would solve my problem.  The events would still ping-pong, as each chart would trigger a new `my.zoom` with itself as the source.  I would probably have to pass the initial `source` value along in each event handler to be sure that a chart does not trigger an event when reacting to an event chain it originally triggered.  This might work, but would not be very elegant.

Comment: @willOEM: Yeah, you would need to echo source -- but I don't see anything inelegant about it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a D3-specific solution to my problem:

The D3 event object, `d3.event` contains a nested object, `sourceEvent`, which represents the stack of previous events which triggered the D3 event. The bottom event in this nested object is a simple DOM event.  For example, with zooming, this could be a mousewheel or clicking event.  In my example, the custom event is represented as a plain object with all of the usual event keys and attributes, so I altered my zoom event event handler like so:

```
var zoom =  d3.behavior.zoom()
.on("zoom", function(e){
    // do stuff...
    if (typeof d3.event.sourceEvent.sourceEvent != 'object'){
        $("#chart-div").trigger({
            type: "my.zoom",
            translate: d3.event.translate,
            scale: d3.event.scale
        });
    }
});
```

What this new test does is checks to see if the `sourceEvent` has a parent event, and if so, makes sure it is not a plain object (my custom event).  Now, when I zoom one chart, it triggers a `my.zoom` event, which triggers the zoom functionality on the second chart, but without the second chart triggering its own `my.zoom` event.

It would be nice to know if there is a similar generic method for handling JavaScript events, but for my use-case, this solution will probably do.